# Python Regex - not more than 10 char

Tags: python, regex

`string1 = 'STUDENT001'`
`string2 = 'STUDENT1111'`

the regex - `re.match('[\d|\D]{0, 10}', string1) # returns the search - student001`

the regex - `re.match('[\d|\D]{0, 10}', string2) # returns the search - student111`

From the above examples, our expected output is - the pattern matches the `string1` and the pattern does not match the `string2` because the `string2` contains 11 characters

here the pattern matches the length of characters in a range of 0 to 10, but how to mention that this pattern does not allow when the length of characters is more than 10

thanks

Comment: You could also just check the length of the string directly, instead of relying on the regex.

Comment: @karlKnechtel, Actually, I had other conditions, so checking the length with if else statement is not optimal, that's why I am checking with regex with matching pattern